# Laravel - Passing data to a controller function in a composer through @include

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I want to render a partial view using:

```
@include('partial.view', array('view_data' => $view_data))
```

Now on this view I have a view composer:

```
View::composer('partial.view', 'TheController@theMethod');
```

The variable $view_data is visible inside the view, but not inside the view composer method that renders before the view.

I want to access $view_data (passed through @include) inside the @theMethod method. How can I achieve this? Maybe there is a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`offsetGet()` on the view lets you retrieve variables that have been injected into the view:

```
public function theMethod($view){
    $viewData = $view->offsetGet('view_data');
}
```